# Keeping state when rendering page from the server side

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate, singlepage

I'm currently building a single page app using backbone.js

In order to keep all application pages accessible and crawl-able I made sure that the server side can also render the pages when accessing them directly.

The problem is as follows:
When pushState is not available it initiates the router using the current URL (e.g. if I accessed a url with http://example.com/example the router will build the hash fragment on top of that url)

So:

1. Is there any way of handling this (besides redirecting the use)
2. If you are redirecting as soon as the JS (using pushState feature detection) you still have a problem of urls not having hash signs.

Generally asking, is there a better approach of designing this kind of application?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

I think the evolving consensus is pushstate or nothing (ie to degrade web 1.0 and drop hash-bang routing all together) if SEO-friendly browsing matters to you.

Its one of the reasons I don't use Backbone.js and just use **PJAX** is that pushstate and DOM rendering times are so good you can be single page with very little JS and hash-bang routing has always been rather hackish.

Thus an option is to not use Backbone's router all together and just let something like PJAX (or DJAX or something similar) do the routing work and let Backbone just do the inner page event/rendering stuff (ie validating forms, modal windows, etc..).